# how to access arraylist belonging to an object inside an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been stuck on the same problem for days and have googled everything I can think of and I give up. I am trying to write a program where you're supposed to first create a person object, and afterwards be able to give that person different types of belongings. I'm putting each created person in an arraylist and every person is supposed to have their own inventory which is also an arraylist. I just don't understand how to add items to a specific persons arraylist and how to print that arraylist. Do I have to create a new instance of the arraylist 'belongings' every time I create a new person? and how do I access a certain persons arraylist? Appreciate any sort of feedback because I am super noob.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Sakregister extends Programskelett{

public static ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();


protected boolean nextCommand(){
    String command = readString("> ").toLowerCase();

    switch(command){
    case "print list":
        printAll();
        System.out.println("Program is running");
    break;

    case "print person":
        printUser();
        System.out.println("Program is running");
    break;

    case "create item":
        newItem();

    break;

    case "create user":
        newUser();
    break;

    case "print richest":
        printRichest();
        System.out.println("Program is running");
    break;

    case "crash":
        initCrash();

    break;

    case "quit":
        System.out.println("Program has terminated");
        return true;
    default:
        System.out.println("Not a valid command");
}
    return false;
}

private void printAll() {



    }
private void initCrash() {


    for (Person thisPerson : personList) {
        for (Item thisItem : thisPerson.belongings)
            if (thisItem.name == "Stock"){
                ((Stock) thisItem).setStockCrash(0);
            }
            }
            }

private void printRichest() {


}

private void newUser() {
    System.out.println("enter name: ");

    String name = keyboard.nextLine();

    Person newPerson = new Person(name);


    personList.add(newPerson);



    System.out.println("Person added to list");
}

private boolean newItem() {

    System.out.println("enter item type: ");

    String itemType = readString("> ").toLowerCase();

    switch(itemType){

    case "trinket":

        addTrinket();

        break;

    case "stock":

        addStock();

        break;

    case "appliance":

        addAppliance();

        return true;
    default:
        System.out.println("Not a valid item type");
}
    return false;
    }

private void addAppliance() {

    System.out.println("Enter name of appliance: ");

    String appName = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter initial price: ");

    int appInitialPrice = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter level of wear: ");

    int appWear = keyboard.nextInt();

    Appliance newAppliance = new Appliance(appName, appInitialPrice, appWear);

    System.out.println("Enter name of owner: ");

    Object owner = keyboard.nextLine();

    for(Person entry : personList)
               if(entry.equals(owner))
            entry.belongings.add(newAppliance);


}

private void addStock() {

    System.out.println("Enter name of stock entry: ");

    String stockName = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter amount: ");

    int stockAmount = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter price: ");

    int stockPrice = keyboard.nextInt();

    Stock newStock = new Stock(stockName, stockAmount, stockPrice);

    System.out.println("Enter name of owner: ");

    String owner = keyboard.nextLine();

    keyboard.nextLine();

    for(Person entry : personList) {
        if(entry.equals(owner)) {
            entry.belongings.add(newStock);

    }

    }
}

private void addTrinket() {

    System.out.println("Enter name of trinket: ");

    String trinketName = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter number of gems: ");

    int trinketGems = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Choose gold or silver: ");

    String trinketMineral = keyboard.nextLine();

    keyboard.nextLine();

    Trinket newTrinket = new Trinket(trinketName, trinketGems, trinketMineral);

    System.out.println("Enter name of owner: ");

    String owner = keyboard.nextLine();

    for(Person entry : personList)

        if(entry.equals(owner))
            entry.belongings.add(newTrinket);



}

private void printUser() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

protected void printMainMenu(){
    System.out.println("Choose a command: ");
    System.out.println("start");
    System.out.println("quit");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sakregister registerProgram = new Sakregister();
    registerProgram.run();

}

}

public class Item{

protected String name;

public Item(String name){

    this.name = name;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return name;
}

    import java.util.ArrayList;



    public class Person{

public String name;
public String items;

public ArrayList<Item> belongings = new ArrayList<Item>();

public Person(String name){

    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;

}


public String toString() {
   return "Name: " + name;
}
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" I just don't understand how to add items to a specific persons arraylist and how to print that arraylist"

Your persons are in the personList, so i would use `personList.get(n)` to get the nth Person.
To add items to the `belongings` you can use `personList.get(n).belongings.add(item)`.

To print an arraylist you can use a normal foreach loop:

```
for(Item i:personList.get(n).belongings){
System.out.println(i.getItemName());
}
```

Do I have to create a new instance of the arraylist 'belongings' every time I create a new person?

The ArrayList `belongings` is a field inside the `Person` class. When you create a person with the constructor all of its fields and variables are created in the memory. This happens every time you create a person, so every object (in your case person in the personList) has its own fields like the `belongings` list.

Comment: get(n) only works for the index right? How do I access someone if I only know their name?

Comment: you can search through the array to find the Person with the right name: `for(Person p:personList){if(p.getName().equals("person")){// do something}}`

Answer (score 0):

The new instance of the `ArrayList<Item> belongings` is already being created each time you create a new `Person` object, so you don't need to create it again anywhere. However, there is currently no getter for `belongings`, so you need to write one to access a given person's belongings. You want something like this:

```
 public ArrayList<Item> getBelongings() {
   return belongings;
 }
```

You'll need to write a public method that accepts an `Item` object and `add`s it to the `belongings` of that `Person`. You shouldn't need help with writing another public method that calls `System.out.println()` on the belongings directly or iterates through them and prints them out.